# What could be causing my WPF modal window to close after a button is pressed?

Tags: .net, wpf, event-handling, modal-dialog

I have a modal window in a WPF application which contains a button. After clicking the button, the modal window is closing. How can I force buttons not to close the window? Of course one button should close the window, but not this one. :)

Comment: Are you setting the `DialogResult` property of the window in the click event handler for the buttons?

Comment: You are right Cody :) I was setting DialogResult property... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're not setting the [**`DialogResult`** property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult.aspx) of the window in the `Click` event handler methods for the buttons.

Setting that property causes the modal dialog to end, causing the window to automatically close and return that value to the [`ShowDialog` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx). You should not set this property until you are ready to close the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have IsCancel or IsDefault set on that button? If so, remove that.

Comment: I did not set these properties.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution that caused my application to close:

In my Menu the MenuItem "File" had a Item "Close". On accident I set the CloseButton_Click-Event to "File". That caused my MenuItem "Save" to always close my application.